# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder

Tags: java, hadoop, java-8, hbase, opentsdb

I try to install and run OpenTSDB in accordance to [the official documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html) I start OpenTSDB using `sudo ./build/tsdb tsd --port=4242 --config=/path/to/opentsdb/src/opentsdb.conf --staticroot=build/staticroot --cachedir="$tsdtmp"` Everything seems to be working fine however when I try to create metrics using `./tsdb mkmetric mysql.bytes_received mysql.bytes_sent` I get error shown below. Any ideas what is wrong and how can I solve this? If any additional information is required just let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
2018-10-04 14:06:10,133 WARN  [AsyncHBase I/O Worker #1] UniqueId: Failed pending assignment for: mysql.bytes_received
org.hbase.async.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.toComparator(ProtobufUtil.java:1577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.mutate(RSRpcServices.java:2788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42000)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
    ... 3 more

    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.makeException(RegionClient.java:1797) [asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decodeException(RegionClient.java:1815) [asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:1492) [asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:88) [asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.handleUpstream(RegionClient.java:1230) [asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:142) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.java:36) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.sendUpstream(HBaseClient.java:3857) [asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
2018-10-04 14:06:10,135 ERROR [main] UidManager: error while processing mysql.bytes_received
org.hbase.async.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.toComparator(ProtobufUtil.java:1577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.mutate(RSRpcServices.java:2788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42000)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
    ... 3 more

    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.makeException(RegionClient.java:1797) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decodeException(RegionClient.java:1815) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:1492) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:88) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.handleUpstream(RegionClient.java:1230) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:142) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.java:36) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.sendUpstream(HBaseClient.java:3857) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError`- appears when jvm trying to load class, and that class is not found. Or trying to initialize incompatible version. I suggest you change your libraries, if that helps.

Comment: I know but I have no idea where and what type of library should I add. Any suggestions?

Comment: This line `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil` tells me that a jar that is having this class `ProtobufUtil` is not found and hence could not be initialized. Try to include jars that has `protobuf`.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade the library, first. If it still gives same error, then downgrade (in other words, if it is version 2 which is giving you error, then downgrade to version 1). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the full context of what you are doing, you could find that class in various HBase-related packages. In my context, the most obvious choice would be `hbase-client-x.x.x.jar` (x.x.x being the version of HBase suitable to you).

You can see them all here, pick the version that is suitable to you, and either downloaded or update your pom.xml accordingly:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client

If this specific jar doesn't suit you, there are a few others where chis class could be found.

If you use Eclipse, there is a handy tool that allows you to see what jars contain the class you need, and this way you can see what makes most sense given what you are doing. Under Mac, you can press `CMD+Shift+T` and enter the class name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found file `/hbase/lib/hbase-shaded-protobuf-2.1.0.jar` and when I execute `jar tf /hbase/lib/hbase-shaded-protobuf-2.1.0.jar` there is no `ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder.class` I downloaded https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase.thirdparty/hbase-shaded-protobuf/2.1.0 and there isn't also `ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder.class`. Any ideas what can I do now?

Comment: What version of hbase are you using?

Comment: I am using `HBase 2.0.2`

Comment: I just downloaded the JAR from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/2.0.2. Viewing it, I see there is a class org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/ProtobufUtil.class in there

Comment: Yes, when it comes to `hbase-client-2.0.2.jar` I have this in path `/hbase/lib/hbase-client-2.0.2.jar` and I agree that it cointains `org/apache/hadoop/hbase/shaded/protobuf/ProtobufUtil.class` and `org/apache/hadoop/hbase/shaded/protobuf/ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder.class`. So the question is why it's not working?

Comment: If you see it and include it when you launch your process, then I can't say why it isn't loading. Sometimes it might also depend on the order in which these JARs are specified and loaded. I won't know how to change this in your particular situation.